# How much data can I store in Java Session?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, memory

We are working in a Tomcat/J2EE application.

In this application we store a lot of data in the session, and I'm wondering how many data can we store with no problems.

What is the minimum restriction? The memory of Tomcat? The JVM?

How can I calculate if I can store it 200k strings?

Comment: Ummm ... why???  Storing that much String data in a session object sounds rather fishy from a design perspective.  Certainly it presents scalability issues.  (Multiply 400kbytes+ by the number of live sessions ...)

Comment: @StephenC You're right. It's caused by a bad design of the database, that we can't change now. We're exploring "workarounds", and one is store a large amount of data on memory. I'm thinking about saying that store this data in memory is bad idea, but I also want put some numbers over the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #1 - You can store as much data as heap size allocated to JVM. Of course, tomcat runs inside the JVM so it will also use some part of the memory allocated.

For #2 - It really depends on the size of the string - 2 bytes are required per unicode character. Take the average size of your string, multiply it by 200k and then make sure you have enough memory allocated.

Comment: "You can store as much data as heap size allocated to JVM" *divided by the expected number of concurrent sessions.* Or maybe the *maximum* number of expected sessions ...

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat runs in a JVM. So if you have a 32 bits jre, you can have a maximum heap size of about 1,7Gb. If you want more, you should switch to a 64 bits jre.

About string allocation, the internal java character encoding is Unicode, so I think it is UTF-8. In order to save space, you may compress those strings using zip and saving them as these were files.